# Performing single shot operations using SharedFlow without casting to needed value

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-mvvm, kotlin-sharedflow

I have the following SharedFlow in my viewmodel -

```kotlin
class HeroesViewModel(private val heroesRepositoryImpl: HeroesRepositoryImpl) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState())
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    private val _uiAction = MutableSharedFlow<UiAction>()
    val uiAction = _uiAction.asSharedFlow()

 sealed class UiAction {
        data class NavigateToHeroesDetails(val heroModel: HeroModel) : UiAction()
    }
```

And I implement the observing of it in my Composable screen -

```kotlin
fun DashboardScreen(
    navigator: DestinationsNavigator,
    viewModel: HeroesViewModel = get()
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val uiAction by viewModel.uiAction.collectAsState(initial = null)

    when (uiAction) {
        is HeroesViewModel.UiAction.NavigateToHeroesDetails -> {
            navigator.navigate(HeroDetailsScreenDestination(uiAction.heroModel)) // Here is where I get the compiler error
        }
        null -> Unit
    }
```

When trying to use the information from the action, the compiler gives me the following error -

`Smart cast to 'HeroesViewModel.UiAction.NavigateToHeroesDetails' is impossible, because 'uiAction' is a property that has open or custom getter`

What would be the correct way verify that the variable is indeed of the type I want?

Answer (score 2):

So the answer that helped me to achieve my goal was to initiate a coroutine using the `LaunchedEffect` block, and inside it collecting the latest UI action -

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(key1 = "") {
        viewModel.uiAction.collect { uiAction ->
            when (uiAction) {
                is HeroesViewModel.UiAction.NavigateToHeroesDetails -> {
                    navigator.navigate(HeroDetailsScreenDestination(uiAction.heroModel))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the `by` delegate then a simple way is to assign to a `val` inside the `when` expression

```kotlin
    val uiAction by viewModel.uiAction.collectAsState(initial = null)
    
    @Suppress("UnnecessaryVariable")
    when (val action = uiAction) {
        is HeroesViewModel.UiAction.NavigateToHeroesDetails -> {
            navigator.navigate(HeroDetailsScreenDestination(action.heroModel))
        }
        null -> Unit
    }
```

There are other ways as well

- `with(uiAction) { when (this) { ... } }`
- `uiAction.run { when (this) { ... } }`
- `uiAction.let { when (it) { ... } }`

If you don't need the `by` delegate, then you can do

```
    val uiAction = viewModel.uiAction.collectAsState(initial = null)

    when (val action = uiAction.value) {
        is HeroesViewModel.UiAction.NavigateToHeroesDetails -> {
            navigator.navigate(HeroDetailsScreenDestination(action.heroModel))
        }
        null -> Unit
    }
```

And if you just need read-only access in the current scope, then you can simplify it to

```
    val uiAction = viewModel.uiAction.collectAsState(initial = null).value

    when (uiAction) {
        is HeroesViewModel.UiAction.NavigateToHeroesDetails -> {
            navigator.navigate(HeroDetailsScreenDestination(uiAction.heroModel))
        }
        null -> Unit
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I found the needed solution and I will post it in a separate answer